# Sorting Columns of dynamically created HTML Table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for the code which can help me to sort the column of the html table created dynamically.
In my code html table is created dynamically within the web service and i need to sort the column.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) is quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

If the table content is not generated by javascript, i suggest it is better to sort at the server side script then load the sorted table content.

or if the content is generated by javascript or an ajax call then try to use a plugin instead of reinventing the wheel [Take a look at datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) a JQuery plugin.